# Is there a visual style guide showing the default UI of visual force pages?

Tags: visualforce, design-patterns, ui

I am a UX designer and am relatively new to SF/VF. I would like to see the default visual styles of VF pages.

Is anyone aware of a visual style guide for VF pages? I get lots of results for CSS codes, but I can't find the corresponding visual component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stephen Herod put together a presentation of examples of a good set of the native visualforce components, it's by no means exhaustive and isn't updated as salesforce makes changes (although I don't think there have been any noticeable ones since this was done), but it should get you started down this path. Take a look at http://limitexception.com/2014/03/30/visualforce-a-visual-reference-guide/

This isn't a style guide as much as it is a good quick reference for the current implementation of salesforce's visualforce styles, but as crmprogdev points out there's nothing more authoritative on the subject at the moment.

Speculatively, that's likely to change as for lightning as it matures.

Answer (score 2):

The closest thing that exists that I'm aware of is the [Salesforce Style Guide for Documentation and User Interface Text](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_pubs_style_guide.meta/salesforce_pubs_style_guide/) which provides terminology and usage guidelines for user interface text and customer-facing documentation materials.

Beyond that, there really is no "visual UX style guide" in the traditional sense. You're already aware of the the default CSS color and page layout styles.

If you're planning to do any Salesforce1 Mobile development, you may be interested in the [Visual Design Considerations Section](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce1.meta/salesforce1/vf_dev_best_practices_design_considerations.htm) of the [Salesforce1 Mobile App Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce1.meta/salesforce1/salesforce1_guide_introduction.htm).

Any other guidance would be contained in the [VisualForce Developer Guide](https://www.google.com/url?q=http://www.shttp://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/alesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/&sa=U&ei=X).